# What is a good substitute for water purification tablets

Tags: water-purification

I have no Water Purification tablets and wanted to know if there was a substitute.

Comment: Well, [bleach and iodine are helpful in water purification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_water_purification#Chemical_disinfection). Where you looking for something specific?

Comment: Depending on where you're going, water purification may be totally unnecessary. For example, the scientific evidence shows that backcountry water in the Sierra is safe to drink without treatment. Different methods of purification also handle different types of bugs. So the place to start would be to tell us where you're going, then we could figure out if there are any nasties that need to be killed off. Then if there are, we could suggest a method that would work on that type of nasties.

Comment: Boil the water, or buy a filter straw.

Comment: @BenCrowell Big advocate of drinking unfiltered from selective sources.

Answer (score 1):

Some methods for purifying water are:

- Iodine
- Bleach
- Boiling
- Filter Systems

Each has pros and cons in terms of taste, purification, convenience, and costs.